# Method not found - get_LdapConnectionTimeout() 

Tags: 2010

After installing the hotfix:

```
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;2300488
```

My Synchronization connection to the AD cannot be populated, because I get a "Method not found" exception:

```
Method not found: 'Int32 Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_LdapConnectionTimeout()'.
```

It looks like an inconsitency, between different parts of the SharePoint installation, where the proxy class does not contain the requested property.
To confirm this claim, I ran from powershell:

```
// after mounting the SPServiceApplicationProxy class in a variable $proxy....
$proxy | Get-Member
```

It returns a reflection of the object - a list of properties and methods, and yes... there is no LdapConnectionTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft support install following:

SharePoint Foundation 2010:
`http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2352346`

and

SharePoint Server 2010: 
`http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2352342`

followed by an executuion of the SP products and technologies configuration wizard:
`psconfig –cmd upgrade –inplace b2b -wait`